# Optimization of Matrix

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimize a matrix using "NMaximize" and "NMinimize".  I increased the "AccuracyGoal", "PrecisionGoal", "WorkingPrecision" and "MaxIteration" to avoid the "Failed to converge". I also try different estimation methods including "Automatic". In case of "NMaximize" "SimulatedAnnealing" and "RandomSearch" are giving results but too much difference in results. In "NMinimize" case all estimate are indeterminate. In my view we have to pick best optimization method. I need recommendations of such method. Problem is given below

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
X = {{1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1},
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -a, 0, 0, a^2, 0}, {1, -a, 0, 0, a^2, 0},
   {1, a, 0, 0, a^2, 0}, {1, a, 0, 0, a^2, 0}, {1, 0, -b, 0, 0, b^2},
   {1, 0, b, 0, 0, b^2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
R = {{1, c/(1 + c), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {c/(1 + c), 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, c/(1 + c), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, c/(1 + c), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
     1, c/(1 + c), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, c/(1 + c), 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, c/(1 + c), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, c/(1 + c), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, c/(1 + c), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c/(1 + c), 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, c/(1 + c)}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c/(1 + c), 1}};
X // MatrixForm;
R // MatrixForm;
R1 = Inverse[R];
X1 = Transpose[X];
ifcomp = X1.R1.X // MatrixForm;
u = Inverse[X1.R1.X] // MatrixForm;
dif = Det[X1.R1.X];
triv = Tr[Inverse[X1.R1.X]];
NMaximize[{dif, {a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0}}, {a, b, c}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 18, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch", MaxIterations -> 10000]
NMinimize[{triv, {a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0}}, {a, b, c}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 18, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch", MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

**Edit:1 I made few corrections in code. Now outcome is different with different methods and convergence issue exist. In my view "a","b" and "c" results should be between 0 and 10.**

Comment: Typo in NMinimize `{0 a > 0 &&` should be `{a > 0 &&`? Eliminates indeterminate results but exposes other errors.

Comment: @creidhne yes, Edited.

Comment: Look at result of `Together[dif]` to see that one is unbounded (numerator has a `c^6` vs, `c^4` in denominator). It appears `triv` will minimize at 1/3. The parameters seem to go to infinity to obtain this, but I cannot tell what is their algebraic relationship as they do this.